# Best way to display rss feed using JQTouch and JQuery

Tags: jquery, rss, jqtouch

I want to develop a JQTouch web app that will display a list of the titles from an rss feed and then display the title and description when the title is tapped. Can someone please suggest a tutorial or resource that could help me?

Answer (score 0):

I've never messed around with JQTouch, but Google provides a [feed API](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxfeeds/documentation/) that allows you to get just about any feed. Maybe you could use one of the [jQuery Google Feed Plugins](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/05/google-feeds-api-jquery-plugin.html).

Note: You don't need to use a key with the google feed api anymore.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to pull in your XML and turn it into JSON so that the nodes are all numbered.   [Use this jQuery plugin - it rocks.](http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/xml-to-json/#tab-Examples-RSS)
2. In the result js function, you need to create an html list and add an onclick to each LI that puts that nodes info into the next jqt div elements.

I am considering putting a tutorial together but haven't had time yet.